# Use Spark scala to create json objects of 1mb max size from dataframe for batch update request bod

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in the form `to_json(struct(userId, dataFields))`, where each row is a json string that holds user data. Each row looks like `{“userId”: “123”, “dataFields”:{“last_read_doc”:123}}`

I want to utilize a third party bulkUpdateUser api, where we can add multiple users in a single POST call. To use this api endpoint the request body needs to be in in the JSON format `{"users":[{"userId":"123", "dataFields”:{“last_read_doc”: 12}}, {"userId":"345", "dataFields":{“last_read_doc”: 122}}]}`.

My dataframe has 1 million rows, and each users object can be of max size `1mb`. How can I accomplish making the request body where each request body has upto 1mb of users

I've tried creating a separate array and appending each row until the array has max size of 1mb then I attempt to create a json string object users using the array but having trouble doing this efficiently or effectively.

Comment: Are you somehow in control of the source of data? Can you have an average size of the items (in JSON)? If so, I wouldn't care about computing the size in live and just group by X items knowing than X items should be under 1MB.

Comment: Otherwise, show us the code you tried and explain what do you think is not efficient.